# Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined in SearchController

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty new to Angular. I am trying to implement a search page using star wars API but getting $scope in undefined. am not sure what am doing wrong here:

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('starApp');

/* Application controller (for top-level auth) */
app.controller('SearchController', ['$location', 'AuthenticationService',
'$scope', '$http',
function($location, AuthenticationService, $scope, $http) {

    console.log('*** SearchController ***');

    $scope.items = [];

    (function getData() {
        var apiURL = "https://swapi.co/api/planets";
        axios.get(apiURL).then(function(response) {
            showDetail(response.data);
        });
    })();

    function showDetail(data) {
        $scope.items = data.results;
    }

}]);
```

I'm injecting $scope into my controller, but still it shows it is undefined.

Comment: Are you sure you are including angular library successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use $http service. here is working snippet:

```js
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

/* Application controller (for top-level auth) */
app.controller('SearchController', ['$location',
    '$scope', '$http',
    function($location, $scope, $http) {

      console.log('*** SearchController ***');

      $scope.items = [];
      $scope.loading = false;
      var apiURL = "https://swapi.co/api/planets";
      $scope.loadData = function() {
       $scope.loading = true;
        $http.get(apiURL)
          .then(function(response) {
            $scope.showDetail(response.data);
             $scope.loading = false;
          });
      };
      $scope.loadData();

      $scope.showDetail = function(data) {
        $scope.items = data.results;
      };

    }
  ]

);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="SearchController" ng-cloak>
    
    <ul ng-if="items.length>0 && !loading" >
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-if="loading">Loading...</div>

  </div>
```